# Loosing transparency in System.Drawing.Image when using ImageResizer for resizing

Tags: c#, image, bitmap, transparency, imageresizer

For my current WPF appliaction I have to down scale some `System.Drawing.Image` ( objects which I load from PNG files (some of them with transparent background). I've tried multiple approaches for the resizing of the images and all of them worked fine in terms of having a smaller image afterwards. But unfortunately they all make the images loose their transparency.

My last try was to use ImageResizer an external library to get the job done as I expected it to handle that problem easily, but I still have the same issue: Original image is displayed with transparent background; Resized image displayed is displayed with black background.

Here's my code for the usage of the ImageResizer library:

```
ImageResizer.Instructions inst = new ImageResizer.Instructions("width=" + newWidth.ToString() + ";height=" + newHeight.ToString() + ";format=png;mode=max");
ImageResizer.ImageJob job = new ImageResizer.ImageJob(originalImage, typeof(System.Drawing.Bitmap), inst);
job.Build();
return job.Result as System.Drawing.Image;
```

These are my other two approaches, which also basically deliver the same result (Image resized: yet; Transparency preserved: Nope):

```
return originalImage.GetThumbnailImage(newWidth, newHeight, null, IntPtr.Zero); // Transparency gets lost

return new System.Drawing.Bitmap(originalImage, new System.Drawing.Size(newWidth, newHeight));  // Transparency gets lost
```

Any ideas on what I have to do in order preserve the transparency while resizing?

Regards

Ralf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even though you're using WPF, you're working with [`System.Drawing.Image`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.image%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) objects, so you can do this:

```
    public static Bitmap ResizeImage(Image imgToResize, int newHeight)
    {
        int sourceWidth = imgToResize.Width;
        int sourceHeight = imgToResize.Height;

        float nPercentH = ((float)newHeight / (float)sourceHeight);

        int destWidth = Math.Max((int)Math.Round(sourceWidth * nPercentH), 1); // Just in case;
        int destHeight = newHeight;

        Bitmap b = new Bitmap(destWidth, destHeight);
        using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage((Image)b))
        {
            g.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.HighQuality;
            g.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
            g.PixelOffsetMode = PixelOffsetMode.HighQuality;
            g.DrawImage(imgToResize, 0, 0, destWidth, destHeight);
        }

        return b;
    }
```

Afterwards, be sure to save it with the PNG encoder:

```
    public static System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageCodecInfo GetEncoder(System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat format)
    {
        ImageCodecInfo[] codecs = ImageCodecInfo.GetImageEncoders();
        foreach (ImageCodecInfo codec in codecs)
        {
            if (codec.FormatID == format.Guid)
            {
                return codec;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
```

and then

```
    codec = GetEncoder(ImageFormat.Png);
    newBitmap.Save(newFile, codec, null);
```

(Note I'm using the standard .Net class libraries rather than a 3rd party library; hope that's OK.)

**Update**

Incidentally, since you are working in WPF, why not use WPF's [image manipulation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)?

```
public static class BitmapHelper
{
    public static void SaveToPng(this BitmapSource bitmap, string fileName)
    {
        var encoder = new PngBitmapEncoder();
        SaveUsingEncoder(bitmap, fileName, encoder);
    }

    public static void SaveUsingEncoder(this BitmapSource bitmap, string fileName, BitmapEncoder encoder)
    {
        BitmapFrame frame = BitmapFrame.Create(bitmap);
        encoder.Frames.Add(frame);

        using (var stream = File.Create(fileName))
        {
            encoder.Save(stream);
        }
    }

    public static void ImageLoadResizeAndSave(string inFile, string outFile, int newPixelHeight)
    {
        BitmapImage image = new BitmapImage();
        image.BeginInit();
        image.UriSource = new Uri(inFile);
        image.EndInit();

        var newImage = BitmapHelper.ResizeImageToHeight(image, newPixelHeight);

        BitmapHelper.SaveToPng(newImage, outFile);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Resize the image to have the selected height, keeping the width proportionate.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="imgToResize"></param>
    /// <param name="newHeight"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static BitmapSource ResizeImageToHeight(BitmapSource imgToResize, int newPixelHeight)
    {
        double sourceWidth = imgToResize.PixelWidth;
        double sourceHeight = imgToResize.PixelHeight;

        var nPercentH = ((double)newPixelHeight / sourceHeight);

        double destWidth = Math.Max((int)Math.Round(sourceWidth * nPercentH), 1); // Just in case;
        double destHeight = newPixelHeight;

        var bitmap = new TransformedBitmap(imgToResize, new ScaleTransform(destWidth / imgToResize.PixelWidth, destHeight / imgToResize.PixelHeight));

        return bitmap;
    }
}
```

Maybe you're losing transparencies converting images in the older format to WPF format?

Comment: Although the question was aiming on the usage of `System.Drawing.Image` I think this is still the right answer: Simply using the `BitmapImage` class, which seems to be more suitable for WPF, solved my issue with the lost transparency.
Furthermore I noticed that the BitmapImage has two usefull properties called `DecodePixelWidth` and `DecodePixelHeight` which make the resizing even more easy for my case.

Answer (score 2):

ImageResizer **always** preserves transparency.

You're losing transparency during the encoding (or display) of the image, which happens *after* you've taken control away from ImageResizer. Instead of passing in `typeof(System.Drawing.Bitmap)`, pass in an output path or output stream.

```
var i = new Instructions(){ Width = newWidth,Height = newHeight, OutputFormat= OutputFormat.Png, Mode= FitMode.Max};
new ImageJob(originalImage, "output.png", i).Build();
```

ImageResizer can't control how an image is encoded if you take a raw Bitmap from it instead.

---

You didn't specific how you're using the results, which is very important. If you are not writing them to disk or a stream, but are instead *displaying* them, then you're looking for the problem in the wrong place. It's likely that the code responsible for compositing the results onto the display surface is failing to treat the image as a 32-bit image, and is instead ignoring the alpha channel.

Comment: I guess you're right. I deleted my answer, it probably wouldn't solve Ralf's problem. Plus I see you're the author of ImageResizer, so you probably know what you're talking about :)

Comment: I have to admit that you were right that the transparency was most probably lost somewhere before or after the usage of the ImageResizer. I therefore tried to use `MemoryStream` for the `source` and `dest` parameters in order to avoid the usage of `System.Drawing.Bitmap` before finally displaying the image. Unfortunately that did not work for me as the `Result` then stayed empty (`Null`). Somehow I must have used the ImageResizer wrong.
However I decided to give dbc's suggestion a try and used the `BitmapImage` class. This solved the problem for me and ImageResizer is no longer needed.